# Windows Forms - Refresh datagrid after insert, delete or update from outside

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, triggers, datagrid

I have a windows form application that is displaying a relatively huge table. I want to refresh my table only if there is an insert, delete or update operation applied.

The data that is being inserted, deleted or updated is not being done within my own application, and is rarely happening. Refreshing my table periodically slows down my application.

In this situation what is the most efficient way to refresh my datagrid records ?

Comment: Possible duplicate question Check out- [refreshing-windows-program-when-other-users-make-changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311741/refreshing-windows-program-when-other-users-make-changes)

Comment: @Ray I don't know if you have read the other question. The outside applications are the developers own application, therefore everyone suggested to implement a `push-notification system`. But when I mean outside, it can be any other application not necessarily mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read down a bit in that question I provided,  there is a section talks about SQL Dependency and Query Notifications.  I would looki [The SQL Dependency object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) and wire that up so that whenever insert/update/delete operations happen, your application is notified and the data is refreshed in your grid, in - memory binding list, etc.

Comment: This is more like a comment please elaborate your answer.